# Updating data on linked models

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Here's my user model,

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, Base):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, max_length=100, unique=True)
    is_advisor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And here's the user profile

```
class UserProfile(Base):
    profile_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile')
    first_name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
```

Here's the routers,

```
router.register(r'user', UserViewSet),
router.register(r'user/profile', UserProfileViewSet, basename='UserProfile')
```

What will be the path to update the Profile for a specific user, say user_id 3. I'm new to django.

Comment: Can you please add `views.py` and `serializer.py` ? It will be easy . Are you using ModelSerializer ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the `lookup_field` that you will set on the view `UserProfileViewSet` which as [documented](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes):

> **`lookup_field`** - The model field that should be used to for performing object lookup of individual model instances

1. If you want to update it based on the related field `UserProfile.user` using the primary key of the other model `User.user_id`, then:

   ```
   class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
       serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
       lookup_field = 'user'  # Or "user_id"
   ```

   URL path would be:

   ```
   http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/user/profile/123/
   ```

   Where `123` is a `user_id` of a user.
2. If you want to update it based on the related field `UserProfile.user` but using another field on the related table e.g. `User.username` (just for the sake of example, let's say it is in your `User` model and is unique)

   ```
   class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
       serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
       lookup_field = 'user__username'
   ```

   URL path would be:

   ```
   http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/user/profile/john_lennon/
   ```

   Where `john_lennon` is a `username` of a user.

---

For your consideration. If you want the id to be consistent between `User` and `UserProfile` in a way that `user_id` is just equivalent to `profile_id`, you might consider just making it the primary key of your `UserProfile`

```
class UserProfile(Base):
    profile_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile', primary_key=True)
    ...
```

That way, your `lookup_field` can just be `profile_id` as it is just equivalent to `user_id`.

Comment: _ I get a "detail not found" using this approach.